# Autogenerated default move constructor with declared destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

C++11 Standard specifies that auto generated move constructors should not be generated for classes declaring destructors, but the following
code snippet builds and runs correctly:

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
    ~C() { std::cout << "Called C:~C" << std::endl; }

private:
    std::string v;
};


int main()
{
    C c1;
    C c2 = std::move(c1);

    return 0;
}
```

I can build with `clang` 4.2.1 and `gcc` 4.4.3. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization uses the implicitly defined **copy** constructor. In general a move will always fall back to a copy when the move constructor or move assignment operator cannot be used for some reason, since the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are always declared (although they can be deleted under some circumstances).

Comment: Implicitly defining the implicitly declared copy ctor as defaulted (instead of deleted) in the presence of a user-declared dtor is deprecated. So one shouldn't rely on the behaviour in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Brian's answer already explains why your code compiles. To properly check that move ctor is supressed just put a non copyable object into your class, for example `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class C
{
public:
    ~C() { std::cout << "Called C:~C" << std::endl; }

private:
    std::string v;
    std::unique_ptr<char> p;
};
```

Now gcc 5.1.0 produces this error:

> error: use of deleted function ‘C::C(const C&)’
>        C c2 = std::move(c1);